# VS 2019: How to export StyleCop.Analyzers settings

Tags: visual-studio-2019, stylecop

I am using Visual Studio 2019 Professional (16.7.5) edition.  I have installed StyleCop.Analyzers using NuGet. In Solution Explorer, under Analyzers->StyleCop.Analyzers, I can set severity for any style cop rule. Once I change the severity, it must be changing some entries in some configuration file. I want to know where this configuration file is located.  So that I can use the same configuration in other project simply by exporting same file.  I do not want to set severity manually for each project.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this with a new project, and it looks like any of the analyzers that you manually configure a setting for end up in a `.editorconfig` file in the solution folder (which is also linked into the project folder, but it resides on disk at, and will apply from, the solution folder).  For example, I see one created which contains

```
[*.cs]

# SA1000: Keywords should be spaced correctly
dotnet_diagnostic.SA1000.severity = suggestion
```

since that was the setting I changed.